# Build Gradle Failed

Tags: java, gradle, google-drive-api

I'm following Google Drive API instruction to upload file to google drive with java, when i try to "gradle run" in cmd, it announces that "BUILD FAILED" with "Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'"
I'm using java jre 1.8 and gradle 5.4.1 on Eclipse

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'DriveQuickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.33.0'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.32.1'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20211107-1.32.1'
}
```

Comment: How do you expect Java 8 to be able to use Java 11 code and produce Java 11 class files? Java 11 didn't exist when Java 8 was developed. Either install Java 11, or change your `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to 8.

Comment: it worked, i almost forgot it, thanks very much

Comment: Would it be alright if you can post your comment as an answer so that the author and I can upvote it?  @Robert

Answer (score 1):

i change

```
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
```

to

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

and it worked, so it depends on your jdk version